# Height of 2-line UILabel with given font

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How can I calculate the height of a **2-line UILabel** with a **given font**?

I know, that there's a way for general multiline labels to dynamically calculate their size by

```
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = "Some multiline [...] text"

let constraintSize = CGRect(width: aWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let size = aLabel.sizeThatFits(constraintSize)
```

Now, what I want to know: Without knowing the text that'll be written in the label, but only the font, how can I elegantly calculate the height of the label spanning *exactly* 2 (or generally *x*) lines?

*Elegantly* meaning: Maybe somebody finds a better solution than this:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.text = "Some really, really, really, [...] long text to make sure it spans at least 2 lines even for the tiniest fonts."

let constraintSize = CGRect(width: aWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let size = aLabel.sizeThatFits(constraintSize)
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will give you the size for two lines of text. Replace the font with your chosen font:

```
let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
let twoLineHeight = "\n".size(withAttributes: attrs).height
```

Comment: That is indeed elegant: "\n". 
_Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees._

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of **@rmaddy**'s  solution

```
let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
let twoLineHeight = "\n".size(withAttributes: attrs).height
```